# what does this mean this javascript or nodejs - var obj = { is_present: true, status_id: 254 };

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to javascript or nodejs. I have doubts on some basic concepts. 
Can someone explain it to me?

what does this mean in nodejs or javascript?

```
var obj = { is_present: true, status_id: 254 };
```

Comment: It creates an object, pointed to by the variable named `obj`, with two properties; `is_present` and `status_id`. Use `obj.is_present` etc. to access them.

Comment: Also, node.js is written in JavaScript :)

Comment: thanks. i am new to javascript world. 
can we do this way? is it possible ? 
    obj = new obj[1000];

Comment: @tymeJV yes i know. started using nodejs from yesterday. came to know that it is written on javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That defines a variable named `obj` and sets it equal to an object with 2 properties, `is_present` and `status_id`.  `is_present` is initialized to true, `status_id` is initialized to 254.

You can then access those values like this

```
var y = obj.is_present //y will equal true

var x = obj.status_id // x will equal 254
```

or like this

```
var y = obj["is_present"] //y will equal true

var x = obj["status_id"] // x will equal 254
```

Comment: thanks. can we create an array of obj? like
arr = new obj[100] ? is this is possible ?

Comment: javascript is not a typed language, so any array can take any type of object.  To create a new array you can just say `var arr = [];` Javascript arrays don't have set lengths, so there is no need to initialize the length.